# Probability, "good" basket.

Tags: probability

We have 10 balls to divide to 5 baskets, the baskets are numbered 1-5 and we consider a "good" basket one which contains the same ammount of balls as its number.
X = Number of "good" baskets.
Calculate E(X), the average value of X.

This question is under the "Indicators" section of my course, But seeing as everybasket has a different chance to be "good" I dont know how to calculate this, except going into combinatorics but that would take the whole day.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** For $i\in\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, let $X_i$ denote the indicator of the event that basket $i$ is "good". Note that $X=X_1+X_2+X_3+X_4+X_5$.

Then, by additivity of the expectation,
$$
\DeclareMathOperator*{\E}{\mathbb{E}}\E[X]=\sum_{i=1}^{5}\E[X_i]=\sum_{i=1}^{5}P(\text{$i$ is good}).
$$
So, you only need to compute these probabilities.

Comment: Ahh yes, its more straightforward than I thought, I had the fact that the chances are different throw me off, Thanks for the quick reply.